# Where is the source code in the console coming from?

Tags: menus, duplicates

I am having a bit of an issue with menu creation. A bug in WordPress (4.9.4)? --

I am creating a theme and am now adding custom menus. The header menu
is fine now. But the footer menu is mirroring the header menu. In the console the footer is showing div class="menu-main-navigation-container". But, it should be showing the newfooter navigation container. How do I reach the page's HTML to change it to the proper div? I tried changing it in the console, but it won't save it for me and I can't find any page that shows the HTML that I am seeing in the console.

At present I have these files: index.php; header.php; footer.php; functions.php; and, style.css plus two folders that house the js and css files.

I've looked through all of my files and can't find the HTML that WordPress is generating which I see in the console window.

I am using Desktop Server as my local host.

I FOUND IT! I placed an "==" where a "=>" should have gone.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'newfooter')); ?>
```

Comment: The HTML is generated by PHP from in your themes files, look for the code that tells WP to display the menu and edit your question to include it. Also, if editing in your browser dev tools worked, you could hack any website, imagine going to cnn.com and changing the headlines and it saving then having FBI agents on your doorstep 2 days later

Comment: Check your footer.php. Check the menu that's being used there against the backend menu set up.